# How do I change the path delimiter for ltree paths in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, tree, psql, postgresql-9.1, ltree

The path delimiter for ltree in PostgreSQL is '.', so paths look like root.child.grand-child.* in the queries. But I want to use it to store paths of CRN format, where delimiter is ':', or some other delimiter for that matter. Is there a way to do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Not without changing the source of ltree and re-building the extension.